# Is it possible to use Entity framework Core "in-memory database" on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I'm writing an API that I'd like to host on an Ubuntu server, and am wondering whether for testing purposes I can use the "UseInMemoryDatabase" option for testing on the server. I have it running currently, and the default "values" controller works, but those are currently hard coded.

Comment: Try and see perhaps?

Comment: Yes, why would you think it's not possible?

Comment: The server doesn't matter. What matters is the version of EF Core.

Comment: I'm currently using EF Core 2.2.

Comment: Did you try it out? What was the outcome?